# How do I add an animatable CIFilter to my SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, animation, cifilter

I really wish to add a CIFilter to my SKScene. That I can do quite easily in fact by putting the following into my `didMove(to view: SKView)` function of my `GameScene` Class:

```
let grayscaleFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls", withInputParameters: ["inputBrightness" : 0.0, "inputContrast" : 1.1, "inputSaturation" : 0.0])!
grayscaleFilter.name = "grayscale"
self.filter = grayscaleFilter
self.shouldEnableEffects = true
```

Now my issue come with attempting to animate it, to my knowledge the only way to efficiently animate CIFilters is with Core Animation. I know that Core Animations can only be added to CALayer so I tried the following code in my `didMove(to view: SKView)` function of my `GameScene` Class:

```
let grayscaleFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls", withInputParameters: ["inputBrightness" : 0.0, "inputContrast" : 1.1, "inputSaturation" : 0.0])!
grayscaleFilter.name = "grayscale"
let grayscaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "filters.grayscale.inputSaturation")
grayscaleAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
grayscaleAnimation.toValue = 1.0
grayscaleAnimation.duration = 5
view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
view.layer.filters?.append(grayscaleFilter)
view.layer.add(grayscaleAnimation, forKey: "grayscaleAnimation")
```

I get no results at all. No animations. No filter at all. Does anybody know a way to do this in a way that works, and could anyone explain why my current method doesn't work. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do "filters.grayscale.inputSaturation" and "grayscaleAnimation" come from?

Comment: @ElTomato the grasyscaleAnimation is a made up key. The other one is described here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410901-filters

Comment: As far as CABasicAnimation is concerned, what you show in code doesn't make sense.  You should probably animate UIView without CABasicAnimation.

Comment: @ElTomato to my knowledge the only way to animate a CIFilter efficiently is to use Core Animation, so how would I animate the view without CABasicAnimation? And I’m confused by what property I should set to background color

Comment: To my knowledge, you use CABasicAnimation when you have the property of a layer to alter.  When I see your code, there's no accountability as to why you set it to filters.grayscale.inputSaturation.  As far as applying a filter is concerned, I would use UIView.animate.  But I don't really know what you are actually trying to apply it to.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way I know of that works, using only SpriteKit (no Core Animation). First you create the filter, store it:

```
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIExposureAdjust", withInputParameters: ["inputEV": 0])
self.filter = filter // store it
scene.filter = filter // so the whole scene will be filtered
scene.shouldEnableEffects = true
```

Then you create an SKAction that changes a property of the filter.

```
let duration = 1.0
let a = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: duration) { (node, elapsed) in
    let percent = elapsed / CGFloat(duration)
    // Animate inputEV from 0 to 2.5
    self.filter.setValue(percent * 2.5, forKey: "inputEV")
}
a.timingMode = .easeIn
scene.run(a)
```

And if you don't want to filter the whole scene, you can use an SKEffectNode in the same way. But instead of assigning the filter to the scene, you assign it to the SKEffectNode. However, you need to add this line in the SKAction block, after updating the filter's properties:

```
self.myEffectNode.shouldEnableEffects = true
```

Without that line in the SKAction block, the animation won't work. I regard this as a bug. You don't have to do this if you're setting the filter on the whole scene though.